# Generic method evaluating different conditions doing the same function

Tags: java, oop

I have 12 methods like the below threemethods. I noticed all of them are doing the very same function and the only thing changing is the method's name and if condition. Is there any smart way to make one generic method that can handle the below conditions.

Side note: callXCD is a child object for the current object having these methods and its methods like "isNational()" are protected.

```
public int getNationalTelephonyCost(){

    if(callXCD.isNational() && callXCD.isTelephony())
        return Integer.parseInt(callXCD.getDiscountedAmount());
    else
        return 0;
}

public int getOnNetTelephony(){

    if(callXCD.isOnNet() && callXCD.isTelephony() && callXCD.isMobileOriginating())
        return Integer.parseInt(callXCD.getDiscountedAmount());
    else
        return 0;   
}

public int getLocalData(){

    if(callXCD.isLocal() && callXCD.isData())
        return Integer.parseInt(callXCD.getDiscountedAmount());
    else
        return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You can wrap the callXCD in a new object that hides these methods but if you cannot change callXCD you won't get away without multiple if-s.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to extract the conditions as predicate classes. It would be nicer if we could have Lambda expressions, but alas, this is Java.

It could look like this:

```
public interface Predicate {
    public boolean check();
}

public int getSomething(Predicate p) {
    if(p.check())
        return(Integer.parseInt(callXCD.getDiscountedAmount()));
    return(0);
}

public Predicate nationalTelephony = new Predicate() {
    public boolean check() {
        return(callXCD.isNational() && callXCD.isTelephony());
    }
};
public Predicate onNetTelephony = new Predicate() {
    public boolean check() {
        return(callXCD.isOnNet() && callXCD.isTelephony() && callXCD.isMobileOriginating());
    }
};
public Predicate localData = new Predicate() {
    public boolean check() {
        return(callXCD.isLocal() && callXCD.isData());
    }
};
```

You then call this with, for example, `getSomething(localData)` or `getSomething(nationalTelephony)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put a big `if else if else if else` chain into a single method that covers all of your `if` conditions.

For example...

```
public int singleMethod(){
    if(callXCD.isNational() && callXCD.isTelephony())
        return Integer.parseInt(callXCD.getDiscountedAmount());
    else if(callXCD.isOnNet() && callXCD.isTelephony() && callXCD.isMobileOriginating())
        return Integer.parseInt(callXCD.getDiscountedAmount());
    else if(callXCD.isLocal() && callXCD.isData())
        return Integer.parseInt(callXCD.getDiscountedAmount());
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite how the code that calls this looks, but this might be a good candidate for an `enum` with methods; each of these conditions can be simplified to a `boolean` expression on `callXCD`, and you could declare

```
public abstract boolean useDiscountedAmount(CallXCD callXCD);
```